# How to choose modelName in sequelizejs model def

Tags: sequelize.js

If a model's definition is in file named '`sys_log.js`':

```
const { DataTypes, Model } = require('sequelize');
const db = require("../startup/db");

class SysLog extends Model {};  

SysLog.init({
    action:{type: DataTypes.STRING},
    amount:{type:DataTypes.INTEGER},
    doer_id:{type:DataTypes.INTEGER},
    fromadd:{type:DataTypes.STRING},
    toadd:{type:DataTypes.STRING},
    desp:{type:DataTypes.STRING},
    createdAt: DataTypes.DATE,
}, {
    sequelize: db,
    modelName:   //<<==what is the modelName naming convention: 'sys_log'? or 'syslog'. 
    timestamps:true,
    updatedAt:false,
})

 module.exports.SysLog = SysLog;
```

For the model def above, how to choose the `modelName`? Is the model name the same as the file name (`sys_log`)? Or can be any name, such as `syslog` or `systemLogs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be anything but sequelize will do pluralize.

if you want to stop auto-pluraization and want to have same table name as your modelname then you can pass this

```
freezeTableName: true
```

if you want custom table name then you can pass this

```
tableName: 'mysyslog'
```

[doc](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-basics/#:%7E:text=A%20model%20in%20Sequelize%20has,although%20this%20is%20fully%20configurable.)